# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, change-data-capture

I am trying to add [debezium-connector-postgres](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.debezium/debezium-connector-postgres) to my Kafka Connect.

First I validated my config by

PUT http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins/io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector/config/validate

```
{
    "name": "postgres-kafkaconnector",
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "example.com",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.dbname": "my_db",
    "database.user": "xxx",
    "database.password": "xxx",
    "database.server.name": "my_db_server",
    "table.include.list": "public.products",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput"
}
```

It returns this which shows no error:

```
{
    "name": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "error_count": 0,
    ...
```

Then I try add this connector by

POST http://localhost:8083/connectors

```
{
    "name": "postgres-kafkaconnector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "example.com",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.dbname": "my_db",
        "database.user": "xxx",
        "database.password": "xxx",
        "database.server.name": "my_db_server",
        "table.include.list": "public.products",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput"
    }
}
```

The connector got added successfully.

However, I got error when I run

GET http://localhost:8083/connectors/postgres-kafkaconnector/status

```
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=postgres-kafkaconnector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnectionException: ERROR: syntax error
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initPublication(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:180)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.createReplicationSlot(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:351)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.start(PostgresConnectorTask.java:136)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:130)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:208)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2565)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2297)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:236)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initPublication(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:137)
    ... 11 more
```

How can I see the full log especially that 11 more lines? I also checked my Kubernetes pod log, it shows same part without that 11 more lines.

The current error content is not very useful. Any help for further debugging would be appreciate!

---

**UPDATE 1:**

GET http://localhost:8083/connectors

returns

```
[
    "postgres-kafkaconnector"
]
```

Comment: The server logs might give more information

Comment: Do you want to add the second Debezium connector for the postgresql instance?

Comment: @OneCricketeer do you mean Postgres logs?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander oh, this is the first one and only Debezium connector I believe.

Comment: Please provide output of `GET http://localhost:8083/connectors`

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander added in the **UPDATE 1**.

Comment: The database logs should show the queries that attempted to get ran, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we are using Postgres 9.6.12, after switching to Postgres 13.6.

With same setup step, it works well this time.

My best guess is maybe because the debezium-connector-postgres version 1.8.1.Final I am using does not work well with old Postgres 9.6.12.